# Has anyone suffer a recent failure on Instances located on us-east-1b for AWS?

Tags: linux, centos, amazon-ec2

I have servers located on us-east-1b and us-east-1c.  All my servers on 1b are inaccessible.  Is anyone else having this issue on the Amazon Cloud?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see it happening now but it's happenend to me in the past.  It seems to me pretty typical behavior.

Answer (score 1):

And keep in mind that what for you is availability zone us-east-1a might be 1b or 1d for another EC2 account.
The availability zone names aren't identical for everyone, Amazon arranges them in a different way for every EC2 account.